# Continuous and bornological Hochschild homology

Tags: convex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces, hochschild-homology

As far as I understand, given a complex algebra $A$ with a *locally convex topology* $\mathcal{T}_A$ (e.g. $A=C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb C)$ for some manifold M), the topology induces a complete convex *bornology* $\mathfrak{B}$ on $A$. I am aware of two different ways to define the Hochschild homology $HH_{\bullet}(A, A)$ of such an algebra $A$:

1) As the homology of the "continuous" Hochschild chain complex $(\hat{C}_{\bullet}(A, A), d)$ with $\hat{C}_n(A, A):=A^{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}n+1}$ where in the tensor power series we use the *topological projective tensor product*  $\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}$ instead of the algebraic one $\otimes_{\mathbb C}$.

2) As the homology of the bornologically complete Hochschild chain complex $(\hat{C}_{\bullet}(A, A), d)$ with $\hat{C}_n(A, A):=A^{\hat{\otimes}n+1}$ where the tensor powers used to define Hochschild chains of $A$ are bornological.

Q1: I do not understand the relation between both definitions. Are they equivalent? If not, in which cases is it appropriate to use the classical continuous Hochschild homology $1)$ as opposed to the bornological one $2)$? I cannot find any good references on the subject.

Q2: In particular, in the special cases $A=\mathbb C[V]$ and $A=\mathbb{C}[[V]]$ for some complex finite dimensional complex vector space $V$, do the above Hochschild homologies reduce to the standard algebraic  Hochschild homology where the tensor powers are algebraic?

Thank you in advance for your help.